# Set Element in Array 1 to Zero, if corresponding Element in Array 2 is less than Threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

and I am looking for some hints on how to get my problem start.

```
arr1 = [1, 3, 5, 9, 4]

arr2 = [5, 8, 2, 3, 9]
```

How can I set the elements in `arr1` to `0`, if the corresponding element in `arr2 <= threshold`.

```
Threshold = 5
```

Expected output.

```
new_arr = [1, 3, 0, 0, 4]
```

I will eventually scale this to 3D arrays.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think expected output is [0,3,0,0,4]

Comment: I updated the output to match the description. Please update if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
arr1 = [a if b>=5 else 0 for a,b in zip(arr1, arr2)]
```

Or to modify `arr1` in place:

```
arr1[:] = [a if b>=5 else 0 for a,b in zip(arr1, arr2)]
```

Output: `[1, 3, 0, 0, 4]`

Comment: I think "if" condition should be <=

Comment: @Alex given the provided output I assumed this was `<5` to set to `0`, but you're right there is a discrepancy in the question ;) I actually modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about numpy arrays due to your tags and not list you have multiple options. If you want to create a new array, you can do

```py
arr2 = np.array(arr2)
arr1 = np.array(arr1)
new_array = np.where(arr2 <= threshold, 0, arr1)
```

where np.where selects 0 whenever the condition is True, otherwise the entry of the other array at that index.

If you want to change those values to 0 in the source array, you can use logical indexing

```py
arr1[arr2 <= threshold] = 0
```

Comment: I hadn't seen the tag, I was about to add that for 3D arrays it would be better to use numpy ;)

Answer (score 0):

As written, your `arr1` and `arr2` appears to be `list`s, but since you've added NumPy as a tag I will assume that they in fact are NumPy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 9, 4])
arr2 = np.array([5, 8, 2, 3, 9])
```

(if you `print(arr1)` you indeed get what you write). You can now simply do

```py
threshold = 5
arr1[arr2 < threshold] = 0
```

Read it like "set the elements within `arr1` for which the corresponding values in `arr2` are less than `threshold` to `0`".

This will work with multi-dimensional NumPy arrays as well.

To better understand what's actually going on, you can try play around with just `arr2 < threshold`. Try print it out:

```py
print(arr2 < threshold)
```

This is referred to as a *mask*. It is in fact itself a (boolean) NumPy array:

```py
mask = arr2 < threshold
mask[0] = True  # make a change!
arr1[mask] = 42  # now apply the mask
```

Note that in the above examples, `arr1` itself is changed (or mutated). That is, the original data within `arr1` is not kept. If you want to keep `arr1`, take a backup first, or equivalently copy `arr1` to a new array and use that:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 9, 4])
arr2 = np.array([5, 8, 2, 3, 9])

arr3 = arr1.copy()
arr3[arr2 < threshold] = 0  # mutate arr3, keeping arr1 as is
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numpy arrays, your problem can be solved by:

```
threshold = 5

new_arr = arr1*(arr2 >= threshold)
```